# UWP WinUI TreeView programatically scroll to item

Tags: uwp, winui

I am trying to use new `WinUI` toolkit  `TreeView` control. I need to scroll programmatically to specific item.

I cannot find way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, The is no such api in `TreeView` class that used to scroll into view. But you could get `TreeViewList` in TreeView `ControlTemplate`. And it is based on `ListViewBase` that contains `ScrollIntoView` method. For getting `TreeViewList` you could use `VisualTreeHelper` class.

```
public static DependencyObject FindChildByName(DependencyObject parant, string  ControlName)
{
    int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parant);

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        var MyChild = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parant, i);
        if (MyChild is FrameworkElement && ((FrameworkElement)MyChild).Name == ControlName)
            return MyChild;

        var FindResult = FindChildByName(MyChild, ControlName);
        if (FindResult != null)
            return FindResult;
    }
    return null;
}
```

And the TreeViewList name is ListControl in the TreeView style.

```
<TreeViewList x:Name="ListControl" AllowDrop="False" 
              CanReorderItems="False" 
              CanDragItems="False" 
              ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TreeViewItemStyle}" 
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CultureItemDataTemplate}">
    <TreeViewList.ItemContainerTransitions>
        <TransitionCollection>
            <ContentThemeTransition/>
            <ReorderThemeTransition/>
            <EntranceThemeTransition IsStaggeringEnabled="False"/>
        </TransitionCollection>
    </TreeViewList.ItemContainerTransitions> 
</TreeViewList>
```

**Usage**

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var listControl = FindChildByName(treeView1, "ListControl") as ListViewBase;
    listControl.ScrollIntoView(treeView1.RootNodes.LastOrDefault());
}
```