# c# UWP TreeView autoscroll on ItemDrag

Tags: c#, uwp, drag-and-drop, treeview, autoscroll

I'm, facing a very simple and well known problem. I have a treeview in my UWP application, a User can reorder items by drag&drop with a few restrictions. The d&d itself works like expected, but now, when i have a very long list of sub-items to drag to a place very high or low in the tree, i need to have an autoscroll like every user knows from the windows explorer for example, moving the cursor down to bottom activates a scroll... but... how to implement that in UWP? Is there any default property I'm missing? Or how can i even scroll to a specific node in the tree? There are tons of info for Winform or even WPF, but i'm stuck on UWP and was unable to convert a WPF solution to my app.

Does anybody have any hint on that problem?

Edit: here is a shortened version of my XAML:

```
<Page
    x:Class="CookBook.Views.EditCategoryPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:templateSelectors="using:CookBook.TemplateSelectors"
    xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
    xmlns:models="using:CookBook.Core.Models.Entities"
    xmlns:enums="using:CookBook.Core.Models"
    xmlns:winui="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"
    xmlns:behaviors="using:CookBook.Behaviors"
    xmlns:helpers="using:CookBook.Helpers"
    xmlns:interfaces="using:CookBook.Core.Models.Entities.Interfaces"
    xmlns:converters="using:CookBook.Helpers.Converter" xmlns:viewcontrols="using:CookBook.Views.ViewControls" xmlns:treeviewdata="using:CookBook.Models.TreeViewData"
    behaviors:NavigationViewHeaderBehavior.HeaderMode="Always"
    NavigationCacheMode="Disabled"
    Style="{StaticResource PageStyle}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">


    <Grid>
        <Grid>
            <Grid x:Name="mainGrid">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition x:Name="treeViewColumn" Width="350"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualState>
                            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                <!--641 is the default CompactModeThresholdWidth in NavigationView -->
                                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="641" />
                            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Target="header.Margin" Value="0,0,0,0" />
                                <Setter Target="treeViewColumn.Width" Value="350" />
                                <Setter Target="treeViewColumn.MaxWidth" Value="500" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <Grid 
            Background="{ThemeResource SystemChromeMediumLowColor}">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid
                Margin="80,0,0,0"
                x:Name="header">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock
                    x:Uid="TreeViewTitle"
                    Margin="{StaticResource SmallLeftMargin}"
                    Style="{StaticResource ListTitleStyle}"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        <!--Fold all-->
                        <Button
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    x:Uid="TreeView_CollapseAllButton"
                    Content="&#xF165;"
                    FontSize="14"
                    Padding="{StaticResource SmallLeftRightMargin}"
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                    VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                    FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                    Background="Transparent"
                    Click="OnCollapseAll" />
                        <!--expand all-->
                        <Button
                    Grid.Column="2"
                    x:Uid="TreeView_ExpandAllButton"
                    FontSize="14"
                    Padding="{StaticResource SmallLeftRightMargin}"
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                    VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                    FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                    Background="Transparent"
                    Click="OnExpandAll" >
                            <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Glyph="&#xEE47;"/>
                        </Button>
                        <!--Reorder Mode-->
                        <ToggleButton
                    Grid.Column="3"
                    Content="&#xE8FD;"
                    FontSize="14"
                    Padding="{StaticResource SmallLeftRightMargin}"
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                    VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                    FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                    Background="Transparent"
                    IsThreeState="False"
                    RightTapped="ReorderModeRightClicked"
                    IsChecked="{x:Bind ReorderMode, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                        <!--Add-->
                        <Button
                    Grid.Column="4"
                    x:Name="foMenu"
                    x:Uid="Flyoutbutton"
                    Content="&#xE710;"
                    FontSize="14"
                    Padding="{StaticResource SmallLeftRightMargin}"
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                    VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                    FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                    Background="Transparent">
                            <Button.Flyout>
                                <MenuFlyout>
                                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Neue Kategorie" Click="AddCategory" ></MenuFlyoutItem>
                                    <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="btnCatIn" Text="{x:Bind CategoryInText,Mode=OneWay}" Click="AddCategory" />
                                    <MenuFlyoutSeparator />
                                    <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="btnReceipeIn" Text="{x:Bind ReceipeInText,Mode=OneWay}" Click="AddReceipe" />
                                    <MenuFlyoutSeparator />
                                    <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="btnImportFromCK" Text="Import aus Chefkoch" Click="BtnAddReceipeFromCK" />
                                    <MenuFlyoutSeparator />
                                    <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="btnCBCut" Text="Ausschneiden" Click="CBCut" />
                                    <!--<MenuFlyoutItem  Text="Aus der Zwischenablage einfügen" Click="MoveReceipe" />-->
                                    <MenuFlyoutSubItem x:Name="btnCBAdd" Text="Einträge einfügen">
                                        
                                    </MenuFlyoutSubItem>
                                </MenuFlyout>
                            </Button.Flyout>
                        </Button>
                    </Grid>

                    <winui:TreeView
                BorderBrush="Beige"
                BorderThickness="1"
                x:Name="treeView"
                Grid.Row="1"
                SelectionMode="Single"
                
                CanBeScrollAnchor="True"
                        
                ItemsSource="{x:Bind CategoryItems,Mode=TwoWay}"
                ItemInvoked="OnItemInvoked"
                ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource TreeViewTemplateSelector}"
                
                
                DragItemsStarting="TreeView_DragItemsStarting"
                DragItemsCompleted="TreeView_DragItemsCompleted"
                
                Width="auto">
                        <winui:TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="winui:TreeViewItem">
                                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                            </Style>
                        </winui:TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    </winui:TreeView>
                </Grid>

                <ScrollViewer
            Grid.Column="1" >
                    <ContentControl
                Content="{x:Bind SelectedItem, Mode=OneWay}"
                ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ContentTemplateSelector}"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" />
                </ScrollViewer>

                <controls:GridSplitter
            Grid.Column="1"
            GripperCursor="Default"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            ResizeDirection="Auto"
            ResizeBehavior="BasedOnAlignment"
            CursorBehavior="ChangeOnSplitterHover"
            Width="16" />
            </Grid>

            <ScrollViewer x:Name="sViewerSingle" Visibility="Collapsed">
                <ContentControl
                Content="{x:Bind SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
                ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ContentTemplateSelector}"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" />
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: Could you share the code you have written? and do you mean autoscroll to the top or bottom when drop complete?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT phu.... maybe i can isolate my snippet and make a demo application, otherwise we will have a big code overload. but in before: i mean an autoscroll WHILE dragging, not on drop. pls, test this behaviour in windows explorer, drag a file from the very top to the very end of a directory list, the explorer will scroll down, when the cursor hits the bottom border

Comment: You may refer this case [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52034035/7254781).

Comment: Yes, tried that, i had problems getting the proper parent... i made a small sample repository. you can drag and drop every leaf in every group, but how to achieve that scrolling behaviour: https://github.com/tzdlr/TreeViewReorderSample

Comment: I tested your code I found your treeview could not scroll as normal, please use Grid to replace the default StackPanel  as treeview's parent and try drag the item again, you will find result.

Comment: you're right.... my original treeview is already wrapped in a grid, but doesn't scroll as expected :(

Comment: that's interesting, does your code sample could scroll when you drag item  trending down or up?

Comment: added a shortened version of my page xaml

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232572/discussion-between-nico-zhu-msft-and-tinoz).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> c# UWP TreeView autoscroll on ItemDrag

`TreeView` contains scrolling behavior when you drag item trending down or up.
During checking your `xaml` code, The `ScrollViewer`  overlays the TreeWiew, and it will effect `TreeView`  and prevents the scroll behaviour. Please try to remove it to other area.

Comment: you're right, there is a doubling in my xaml.... one scrollviewer is collapsed, but seems to overlay the complete page and prevents scrolling! Thanks for pointing at that! After removing the <ScrollViewer x:Name="sViewerSingle" Visibility="Collapsed"> viewer it works like a charm!